# JPA Cannot Aquire datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I've created the datasource using the persistence unit wizard in netbeans (8.0.2). But when running the project on glassfish, it cannot find my datasource.

**Exception**

> Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [blogdb]. Internal
>   Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'blogdb' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: blogdb not found]

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="BloggerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>blogdb</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**glassfish-resources.xml**

```
<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="post-gre-sql_2TX33_r0457020Pool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="serverName" value"server.domain.com"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="51415"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="2TX33"/>
    <property name="User" value="user"/>
    <property name="Password" value="pass"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://server.domain.com:51415/2TX33"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="blogdb" object-type="user" pool-name="post-gre-sql_2TX33_r0457020Pool"/>
```

I'm using EclipseLink JPA 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I had an other application deployed on the glassfish server which used the same jta-datasource.